# Building a php mailer with copy-and-paste email address textarea (field)

Tags: php

I am novice in building php mailer. I have built the form with FROM ADDRESS, SENDER'S NAME, REPLY-TO, MESSAGE BODY and THE PASTE EMAIL (textarea) fields. The problem however, is the script. I used the explode function to convert the value of PASTE EMAIL field to an array. I used array_walk function but I seem not be getting right. I need a function that can pick each email address from this array and send a copy of the message to it. 
see my script below:

```
<?php
function function_to_be_applied($finaldest_email, $key){
    require_once "Mail.php" ;
    global $fromemail;
    global $message;
    global $fromname;
    global $subject;

    $to = $finaldest_email;
    $from = "{$fromname} <$fromemail>";
    $subject = $subject;
    $host = "mail.mydomain.com";
    $body = $message;
    $smtp_username = "helpdesk@mydomain.com.com";
    $smtp_password = "password111";
    $header = array('From' => $from, 'To'=>$to, 'Subject'=>$subject, 'replyTo'=> $replyto);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array('host'=>$host, 'auth'=> true, 'username'=> $smtp_username, 'password' =>  $smtp_password, 'port' => 2626));
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $header, $body);
    if(PEAR::isError($mail)){return true;}else{return false;}

    sleep($seconds);
}

//Output from the form

$seconds = $_POST['seconds'];
$subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
$fromname = trim($_POST['fromemail']);
$fromemail = trim($_POST['fromemail']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);
$replyto = trim($_POST['replyto']);
$dest_email = trim($_POST['dest_email']);
$emailarray = explode("\r\n", $dest_email, 200);
$finaldest_email = array_unique($emailarray );

//using array_walk() function

if( true == array_walk($finaldest_email, 'function_to_be_applied' )){

    echo "Number of email sent: ".count($finaldest_email);

}

?>
```

I did not include the form here. I will appreciate it if somebody can help me out.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Quick look shows that you aren't `global`ing everything you're using in `function_to_be_applied()` such as `$replyto`, `$seconds`, and others. Try adding them and see if it helps.

Comment: Please consider re-factoring your code.

Answer (score 1):

For all my PHP mailing needs I use http://swiftmailer.org/ it will allow you to pass an array of "to" address and send to each of them.